# How can I exclude content older than... with Views

Tags: views, datetime

I'm trying to get my head around a Views setting, I can't find how to exclude older than two years old content from Views. I know it has to be somewhere in the Filter section. I would expect this to work, but it doesn't...

Content: Date (field_publication_date) - From date <= now + 2 year

I'm doing something wrong, can someone please help me out?

Thanks a lot!

PS: I'm on Drupal 6...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Show nodes relative to a date with Views page](http://www.codeforbidden.com/drupal/tutorials/show-nodes-relative-date-views) explains how to do it. Did you try post date on *Filter criteria* with the following configuration?

[image]?

Comment: You welcome. If you think my answer is correct, Please check it as accepted for people who visit your question in the future

Comment: This is embarrassing... How can I check it as accepted? I tried upvoting it, but I'm too new around here.

Comment: Under the upvote—downvote  there is a tick sign

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png